# Substition in Bash and associative array

Tags: bash, associative-array, substitution

I want to dynamically declare and unset associative array, but arrays drive me crazy and they do have the best driving licence. :-(

```
names=( Charlie Snoopy Linux Marcia )
intestines=$(printf "%s\n" ${names[@]} | awk '{ print "["$1"]="FNR  }' | tr "\n" " ")
echo $intestines # ok: [Charlie]=1 [Snoopy]=2 [Linux]=3 [Marcia]=4
unset namesAssociative
declare -A namesAssociative=( [Charlie]=1 [Snoopy]=2 [Linux]=3 [Marcia]=4 ) # works ok 
echo ${namesAssociative[Linux]} # OK: 3
```

But:

```
unset namesAssociative
declare -A namesAssociative=( $intestines ) # error
exec "declare -A namesAssociative=( $intestines )" # error
declare -A namesAssociative=( $(printf "%s\n" ${names[@]} | awk '{ print "["$1"]="FNR  }' | tr "\n" " ") ) # error
etc...
```

I guess God punishes me that I have not written that in Python from the very begining... :-)

Comment: `declare -A "namesAssociative=( $intestines )"` should work fine in this particular case. In general, this is a hack and not reliable at all.

Comment: When I reproduce your case, the declaration of `namesAssociative` produces the error _bash: namesAssociative: $intestines: must use subscript when assigning associative array_, from which I conclude that word splitting is not done after parameter expansion in this context. I don't know why this is the case, but I think this would be a valid question. Just mentioning that you get 'error', without saying what error, is not really helpful. BTW Your `exec` command does not make sense; you would need an executable file as argument. Did you mean `eval` here?

Comment: yes, yes, yes. eval not exec... :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as you expect and is made safe using the `%q` format indicator for the associative array's keys.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

names=( Charlie Snoopy Linux Marcia )

# shellcheck disable=SC2155 # Intended dynamic declaration
declare -A namesAssociative="($(
  for i in "${!names[@]}"; do
    printf '[%q]=%d ' "${names[i]}" $((i + 1))
  done
))"


declare -p namesAssociative
```

or Alternatively if your names array is not sparse:

```sh
declare -A namesAssociative="($(
  i=1
  for k in "${names[@]}"; do
    printf '[%q]=%d ' "$k" $((i++))
  done
))"
```

Comment: Yes. This is the mistake: This works: declare -A namesAssociative="( $intestines )". This does not work: declare -A namesAssociative=( "$intestines" ). That is why it drives me crazy... :-) Thanks Lea!

Answer (score 1):

Easier demo, putting associative array name `arr` in list:

```
assoc_list="arr[first]=1 arr[second]=2 arr[third]=3"
unset arr
declare -A arr

eval $assoc_list

echo ${arr[second]}
2
```

Another demo setting associative array name arr later:

```
assoc_list="[first]=1 [second]=2 [third]=3"
# set associate array name as variable with value arr 
assoc_arr_name=arr
# create assoc_array_list from assoc_list
assoc_array_list=${assoc_list//[/$assoc_arr_name[}
echo $assoc_array_list
arr[first]=1 arr[second]=2 arr[third]=3


unset $assoc_arr_name
declare -A $assoc_arr_name

eval $assoc_array_list

echo ${arr[second]}
2
```

In more general way:

```
keys_arr=(first second third)
values_arr=(1 2 3)
map_name=assoc_arr
unset $map_name
declare -A $map_name
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#keys_arr[@]} ; i++)); do 
    eval $map_name[${keys_arr[i]}]=${values_arr[i]};
done
echo ${assoc_arr[second]}
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are insisting too strongly on creating the array from a dynamic string literal in one go, which, depending on various peculiarities of the order of expansion, may require an `eval` or the like.

Maybe don’t push it that hard and use a for-cycle instead:

```sh
declare -a names=( Charlie Snoopy Linux Marcia )
declare -Ai indices1 indices2  # to show two different options
declare -i index

for index in "${!names[@]}"; do
  indices1["${names[index]}"]=$((index + 1))      # option 1
  indices2+=(["${names[index]}"]=$((index + 1)))  # option 2
done

((${#indices1[@]} == ${#indices2[@]})) || echo heck blah

for name in "${!indices1[@]}"; do
  echo "${name}: $((indices1["${name}"])) $((indices2["${name}"]))"
done
```